# Projective modules over PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> I can't find the proof of this corollary: if $R$ is a PID, then every finitely generated projective $R$-module is free.

Please help me.

Comment: What does "find the proof" mean?

Answer (score 4):

A finitely generated projective $R$-module is a direct summand of a finitely generated  free module. Furthermore, a submodule of a finitely generated free module over a P.I.D. is free.